# Mobile Version is loading slightly zoomed in

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I need some help figuring out why on mobile my site loads slightly zoomed in on the right. I can zoom it back out to normal but why is it loading like this. Any help is appreciated. I'm obviously new to web development. If you need the code let me know. But you should be able to view it all from page source.

THE WEBSITE URL:
http://www.thebitpouch.com

Thanks Again,

Answer (score 0):

Your `body` element has `min-width: 400px;` - erase or change that, this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your style sheet, change `min-width: 400px;` to `min-width: 320px;` in the `body{}` style.